# convert each image in a directory to bitmap

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap

I am trying to get all the images from a directory, then convert each one to a bitmap so I can get there attributes (height, width, etc.).  I have the "using System.Drawing", but I'm having throuble with the FromFile part.  Not really sure what to do from here, as I cannot figure out what path to actually get the file from.

```
        // get all files from directory
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\ahaycraft\Desktop\TestImages");
        var directories = di.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        Console.WriteLine("Done");


        foreach (FileInfo d in directories) 
        {
         //convert images to bmp;
            using (var bmp = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(""))
        {
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`FullName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.fullname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to get full path of the file.

```
using (var bmp = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(d.FullName))
```

Or, if you are not interested in other attributes of a file and you just need *path*, use `Directory.GetFiles` method instead.

```
var filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\ahaycraft\Desktop\TestImages",
                                    "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (var path in filePaths)
{
    using (var bmp = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(path))
    {
       // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  That got me one step further along this thing.  I appreciate it.